# Page to run Test Classes

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, page-layout, runas

I have a urgent requirement to make a page in which list of all classes be there with the check box embedded and having button Run. If i select one or more than one classes and click on run button(Run Test) the test class associate with the particular class should run.
please help me out of this requirement.

**Page Layout**

[image: Visualforce page]

**Code for page**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="classdemo">


<html>
<head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var checkedbox = new Array();
        function checkAll(ele) {
         var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
             if (ele.checked) {
                 for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                     if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                         checkboxes[i].checked = true;


             }
         }
     } else {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             console.log(i)
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = false;
             }
         }

     }
     console.log('*****'+ele.checked);

 }


     function Selectedbox(name,checkbox){
     //var name = name;

         console.log('>>>>>>>'+name); 
         if(checkbox=="true"){


                     checkedbox.push(name);
                     console.log('>>>>>>>'+selectedboxes);    
             }
         }


    function populatechecked(name,checked){
        if(checked == true && $.inArray(name, checked) == -1){

        checkedbox.push(name);
    }
    else if(checked == false && $.inArray(name, checked) != -1){
        var index = checkedbox.indexOf(name);
        //removeEventList.splice(index, 1);
        checkedbox.splice(index,1);
        }

    }

    </script>
<apex:form >
<center>
<div>
<table border="3" style="width:300px; ">
<h1 style="font-size: 20px;">Classes</h1><br></br><br></br>
<th><input type="checkbox" id ="SelectAll" onClick="checkAll(this);" name="chk[]"/><b>Select All</b><hr></hr></th>
<apex:repeat value="{!labellist}" var="abc">
    <tr>

        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="selected" onchange="Selectedbox('{!abc.Name}',this);" class="checkedcase"></input>
          {!abc.Name}
        </td>


    </tr>
</apex:repeat>

</table>
</div>
<br></br>

    <apex:commandButton value="Run Test"/>
        </center>
    </apex:form>

</body>
</head>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

**Code for class**

```
    public class classdemo{
public list <ApexClass> labellist{get;set;}

public classdemo(){
Getlist1();
}
public list<ApexClass> Getlist1(){
    labellist = [select Name from ApexClass];
      return labellist;
    }

}
```

Comment: this looks like you are asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: Just want a further step so i can move forward...don't want you to write a code for me.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce support following way to execute a test class

- The Salesforce user interface
- The Force.com IDE
- The Force.com Developer Console
- The API

In your scenario you can execute test class using API but if you don't know how to call with API you can use a new feature called **Running Tests Using ApexTestQueueItem** (in beta release) which will submit your test class for test execution.

I assuming that you have all test class ids which you are going to execute so after getting class ids you can use following code

```
ApexTestQueueItem[] queueItems = new List<ApexTestQueueItem>();
queueItems.add(new ApexTestQueueItem(ApexClassId=PASS YOUR CLASS ID HERE));
insert queueItems;
```

Comment: Thanx buddy...It worked.

Comment: great. close this question then.