# Page to Run Classes

Tags: unit-test, runas

I have a urgent requirement to make a page in which list of all classes be there with the check box embedded and having button Run. If i select one or more than one classes and click on run button(Run Test) the test class associate with the particular class should run.
please help me out of this requirement.

```
PageLayout
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qmsU.png

Comment: Why you need such functionality? isn't standard one enought?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page to run Test Classes](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98434/page-to-run-test-classes)

Answer (score 2):

You can run tests by using [AsyncTestQueueItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apextestqueueitem.htm). Simply loop over the elements, building a list of these items, and assign the ApexClassId for each class you want to run, then insert the list of items. Salesforce will run those asynchronously, which you can pick up later by running a scheduled class every few minutes to see if the tests finished, or use an apex:actionPoller element to periodically check for results while the Visualforce page is open.